# How to access JSON value from WordPress rest api in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic. I want to access the a particular value from WordPress  rest API.

I want to access this value from api. `title:
rendered: "04:00 PM &#8211; 07:00 PM"`

**.ts file**

```
 viewTime(){

   let url = '';


    this.http.get(url, this.config.options)
    .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.title)

                            }, (err) => {
                            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            title: 'Error',
                            subTitle: 'Please check your credentials',
                            buttons: ['OK']
                                    });
                             alert.present();
                             });
                             }
```

But `console.log(response.title)` gives undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an array, so you have to loop over collection to get access to each element of an array.

```
this.http.get(url, this.config.options)
.map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.items = response;
      response.forEach(item => console.log(item.title))
    });
```

**View**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
      <ion-select  interface ="popover">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
           <ion-option > {{item.title.rendered}}</ion-option>
        </div>
      </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks you sir solve my problem..Can you tell me how to access these title value in ion-select..?have you any idea

Comment: @Saifkhan you want to populate an value?

Comment: Yes sir using ion-select. and sir how to remove this  ' &#8211;'  with -  between two time slot.

Answer (score 0):

To display the time slot correct, you can use something like this:

```html
 <p [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></p>
```

like in the above example, do something like this:

```js
let times: string[];
response.forEach(item => times.push(item.title.rendered);
```

Then in HTML:

```html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.selectedTime" multiple>
  <ion-option *ngFor="#time of times" [value] = "time" [checked]="false">{{time}}   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Is it not working in a ion-select or also not working in a normal <p> in the ion-content?

Comment: not working try with ion-select.i have not try with ion-content.

Comment: <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
          <ion-select  interface ="popover">
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
               <ion-option > {{item.title.rendered}}</ion-option>
            </div>
          </ion-select>
    </ion-item>